# pandas MultiIndex : Get value at a particular level and iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for the equivalent of `at` of `DataFrame` for `MultiIndex`.

My present implementation uses:

```
mi = df.columns # This is a multi-index
mi.get_level_values(level_name)[i]
```

I am afraid this is not good for performance. Is there any other value to read a particular `level` at index `i`?

#### Example :

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], names=['i', 'j'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(9)}, index=mi)

df

     x
i j
1 4  0
  5  1
  6  2
2 4  3
  5  4
  6  5
3 4  6
  5  7
  6  8

df.index.get_level_values('j')[3]
4
```

Is there any short alternative to `df.index.get_level_values('j')[3]`

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: Yes, please find the updated question with an example.

Comment: Not sure if exist better solution...

Comment: if u know the number of levels, u can play with the index to get ur values : ```df.index[3][-1]``` should give u the same value as ```df.index.get_level_values('j')[3]```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, I guess you could subset your DataFrame. Something like:

```
df.loc['level'] # In case there is more than one level: df.loc[('level1': 'level2')]
```

This will give you the row (or rows), and from there you can subset again vertically. Subsetting in both directions simultaneously would look something like:

```
df.loc['your_desired_column', 'level1': 'level2']
```

In case you have more than one index, the sintax to subset based on the outer index and the inner differs.

Outser: use strings
Inner: use tuples

As in:

```
df.loc['level1':'level2'] # Outer
df.loc[('outer1', 'inner1'):('outer2', 'inner2')] # Outer & Inner
```

I hope you find this helpful!

Comment: I am interested in getting the values of the multi-index object (not from dataframe). Sorry if the question was not clear enough. I have updated it now.

Answer (score -1):

Check [Basic indexing on axis with MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/user_guide/advanced.html) documentation from pandas.

Here are some examples:

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux          
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
A       0.895717  0.805244 -1.206412  2.565646  1.431256  1.340309 -1.170299 -0.226169
B       0.410835  0.813850  0.132003 -0.827317 -0.076467 -1.187678  1.130127 -1.436737
C      -1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  0.569605  0.875906 -2.211372  0.974466 -2.006747

In [25]: df['bar']
Out[25]: 
second       one       two
A       0.895717  0.805244
B       0.410835  0.813850
C      -1.413681  1.607920

In [26]: df['bar', 'one']
Out[26]: 
A    0.895717
B    0.410835
C   -1.413681
Name: (bar, one), dtype: float64

In [27]: df['bar']['one']
Out[27]: 
A    0.895717
B    0.410835
C   -1.413681
Name: one, dtype: float64

In [28]: s['qux']
Out[28]: 
one   -1.039575
two    0.271860
dtype: float64
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26027406)

Comment: Great, I'll edit and pull the main part of link here.